# The imported project Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found error while creating Docker Image using Docker file

Tags: docker

I am trying to create Docker Image and while running `Run dotnet build xxxxxx.csproj -c Release -o /app/build` I am getting below error.

> The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Can anyone suggest me the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer

I was running wrong command to build a project based on ASP.Net framework 4.7.2.
Instead of using RUN DOTNET BUILD, I needed to use RUN msbuild  command. It solved my issue. It is working now.